# Server's php hacked. Is there a way to target a specific string+tags?

Tags: php, bash, grep

A friend of mine (who doesn't like strong passwords ...) got his server hacked and i'm trying to help him.

Basically, a lot of php files on the server have had lots of stuff added on line 1 between two php tags.

Something like this:

```css
1. <?php lots-Of-Stuff-I-Can-Target-Easily-With-Grep ?><?php
2. Line 2 and beyond, the file is unchanged.
```

So my question is: is there a way via grep - or something else - to just target the first php tags with everything in between to delete it? In the exemple above, on line 1: everything *but* the second opening php tag.

I know I could target line 1 and just replace with an opening php tag, but to avoid any problem, i would much prefer target and delete the exact thing i want out.

There is way too many files to do it by hand. Any ideas?

Comment: Most PHP IDE's should be able to do this. Just Search-and-Replace all things matching that tag. Make sure you have a backup in case you IDE get's overzealous. On the subject of backups: perhaps you should lecture your friend on why he should have had one in the first place.

Comment: Hey Ben, i went with Scheff solution but thank you nonetheless !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fully agree with [Ben Hillier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2863018/ben-hillier)s comment. (I mean especially the part with the back-up as I have only little knowledge about PHP.) However...

The following **sed** command can be used:

```
sed 's/^<?php .* ?>\(<?php.*\)$/\1/'
```

Alternatively, it can be done with **awk**:

```
awk '/<\?php .* \?><\?php/ { $0 = gensub(/^<\?php.*\?>(<\?php.*)$/, "\\1", 1, $0) }{ print }'
```

or with the additional condition `NR==1` to ensures that the test/replacement is done on first line only:

```
awk 'NR==1 && /<\?php .* \?><\?php/ { $0 = gensub(/^<\?php.*\?>(<\?php.*)$/, "\\1", 1, $0) }{ print }'
```

One of these commands (cleverly combined with `find`) should do the job.

Please, notice the distinct escapings which are necessary in **sed** vs. **awk**.

And, as [Ben Hillier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2863018/ben-hillier) already recommded: **Don't forget to backup before.**

Demonstration:

```
$ echo '<?php lots-Of-Stuff-I-Can-Target-Easily-With-Grep ?><?php' \
> | sed 's/^<?php .* ?>\(<?php.*\)$/\1/'
<?php

$ echo '<?php' | sed 's/^<?php .* ?>\(<?php.*\)$/\1/'
<?php

$ echo '<?php lots-Of-Stuff-I-Can-Target-Easily-With-Grep ?><?php' | awk '/<\?php .* \?><\?php/ { $0 = gensub(/^<\?php.*\?>(<\?php.*)$/, "\\1", 1, $0) }{ print }'
<?php

$ echo '<?php' | awk '/<\?php .* \?><\?php/ { $0 = gensub(/^<\?php.*\?>(<\?php.*)$/, "\\1", 1, $0) }{ print }'
<?php

$ echo '<?php lots-Of-Stuff-I-Can-Target-Easily-With-Grep ?><?php' | awk 'NR==1 && /<\?php .* \?><\?php/ { $0 = gensub(/^<\?php.*\?>(<\?php.*)$/, "\\1", 1, $0) }{ print }'
<?php

$ echo '<?php' | awk 'NR==1 && /<\?php .* \?><\?php/ { $0 = gensub(/^<\?php.*\?>(<\?php.*)$/, "\\1", 1, $0) }{ print }'
<?php

$ cat >test.txt <<EOF
> <?php lots-Of-Stuff-I-Can-Target-Easily-With-Grep ?><?php
> // contents
> // contents
> // contents
> ?>
> EOF

$ cat test.txt | sed 's/^<?php .* ?>\(<?php.*\)$/\1/'
<?php
// contents
// contents
// contents
?>

$ cat test.txt | awk '/<\?php .* \?><\?php/ { $0 = gensub(/^<\?php.*\?>(<\?php.*)$/, "\\1", 1, $0) }{ print }'
<?php
// contents
// contents
// contents
?>

$ cat test.txt | awk 'NR==1 && /<\?php .* \?><\?php/ { $0 = gensub(/^<\?php.*\?>(<\?php.*)$/, "\\1", 1, $0) }{ print }'
<?php
// contents
// contents
// contents
?>

$
```

Last but not least the awk script for human readers:

```
# catch 1st line with a duplicated "<?php"
NR==1 && /<\?php .* \?><\?php/ {
  # replace the line by everything including and after 2nd "<?php"
  $0 = gensub(/^<\?php.*\?>(<\?php.*)$/, "\\1", 1, $0)
}
{ print } # print any line
```

Comment: Hey Scheff thank you !

Took me a while to understand everything and try it safely, now i'm ready to go - with a lot of backups  !

After a few tries and errors, this worked perfectly :

`grep -rl matchstring  . | xargs sed -i 's/^<?php $pfnbjwxh .* ?>\(<?php.*\)$/<?php/g'`

_$pfnbjwxh_ here allowed me to target this particular peace of vicious code.

Again, thank you !